# Response array of success call back length is undefined

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am getting the response through through ajax jQuery am trying to get the length of the the array its showing as undefined .
Here is the code

data.json file

```
{
  "response": [{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Web Demo"
  }, {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Audio Countdown"
  }, {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "The Tab Key"
  }, {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "Music Sleep Timer"
  }, {
    "id": 5,
    "name": "Music Sleep Timer"
  }]
}
```

and my js file code is:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "data.json",
  type: "GET",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(response) {
    console.log(response);
    console.log(response.length);
  }
});
```

I am trying to print the length of response array its showing undefined instead of length 5 so can anyone please help how to get the length of response length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are checking length property of an object which will be undefined, so instead you need to check the length of inner array.

```
console.log(response.response.length)
// get array by -----^------
```

Comment: thnx its working suppose if I want to pass that response to other function how can I (response.response).Do i need store it in a variable and pass

Comment: @roy : use `response.response`

Comment: ok i thought of storing  response.response in a variable and use it anyways thnx so much

Comment: :Hi suppose am trying to pass the response.response to main function so I have used like as main(response.response)  Its showing error so how can I pass it

Comment: @ror :  can you share the error which is shown in console.

Comment: unexpected token .(dot)  for main(response.response)

Comment: how can i add my data.json file there

Comment: $.ajax({
      url: "data.json",
      type: "GET",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function (response) {
            requestData(response.response);
            /*main(response);
            console.log(response.response);*/
        }
      });

function requestData(response.response)
{
  console.log(response.response);
}

Comment: @roy the function parameter is providing the bug, change it to `function requestData(response) { console.log(response); } `